# How to get the content of only one field in logstash

Tags: logstash

I'm working on syslogs that I receive through the network, but I receive them in a different format because of the fact it travels by the network.

So the real syslog is in a field named "message", and I'd like to make a filter to get the content of "message" and also filter him and send it to a file.

Actually this is how the data looks like :

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-10-12T14:17:16.944Z","message":"<190>key1=\"value1\" key2=\"value2\"","otherKey1":"otherValue1","otherKey2":"otherValue2"}
```

And here is my actual configuration file :

```
input{
 file{
  path => "/var/log/logstash/syslog.txt"
  start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter{
 if ("" in [message]){
   kv{
     value_split => "="
   }
   mutate{
     add_field => {"timestamp" => "%{date} %{time}"}
   }
   date{
     match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
     target => "@timestamp"
     locale => "fr"
   }
   mutate{
    remove_field => ["date", "time", "timestamp"]
   }
   geoip{
    source => "remip"
   }
 }
}


output{
 file{
  path => "/var/log/logstash/systest.txt"
 }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help or advice !

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, you need to jsut keep the fiels *message* in the event.
You can do this with the prune filter which enable a whitelist mechanism.

So add this in your filter :

```
  prune {
    whitelist_names => ["^message$"]
  }
```

After this, only this field must be written in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but where exactly should I have to put this ?

Comment: in flag filter{..}